# Reprojection problem with Rasterio

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rasterio, pixel, affine-transformation

I have already processed so far NDSI map by using Rrasterio, NumPy, os and matplotlib.pyplot for plotting the data.

Now, I would like to eliminate permanent ice from NDSI map. I am facing one major problem reading reprojection. I have one permanent ice global mask having spatial resolution of 1000 meter which is in [EPSG:4326](http://www.epsg-registry.org/?display=entity&urn=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326) in geographic coordinates in unit degree. The NDSI map is in LCC in unit meter ('+proj=lcc +lat_1=40 +lat_2=55 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=10 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs') and also having 1000 meter spatial resolution.

I am unable to burn the permanent ice mask with NDSI map after reprojection and cropping/subsetting AOI with bounding box from shapely.geometry as the reprojection is not giving same rows and same columns after cropping with same box(coordinates). I have found after reprojecting the data there is a slight change in pixel size it converted into 999.999 meter instead of 1000 meter I think, which could be reason of change rows and columns in spite of having the same extent.

What I did actually let me explain -

After processing NDSI map I check the coordinates system by using

```
img= rasterio.open('/scratch/spatra/test_reproject/NDSI.tif')
print(img.crs)

>>>> NONE
```

In that I would define the projection ArcMap then reproject the data but I am very much confused in Python how to assign projection?

So, I did reprojecting the NDSI map twice first with it's own projection ('+proj=lcc +lat_1=40 +lat_2=55 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=10 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs') and 2nd time with 'EPSG:4326' or it's proj4format

Here is the Code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform, reproject, Resampling


#first time I reprojected with it
dst_crs = '+proj=lcc +lat_1=40 +lat_2=55 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=10 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=longlat +no_defs'

#2nd time I reprojected into geographic coordinates
#dst_crs='EPSG:4326' 

with rio.open('/scratch/spatra/test_reproject/ndsi.tif') as src:
    transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(src.crs, dst_crs, src.width, src.height, *src.bounds)
    kwargs = src.meta.copy()
    kwargs.update({
    'crs': dst_crs,
    'transform': transform,
    'width': width,
    'height': height
    })

with rio.open('/scratch/spatra/test_reproject/new/ndsi_reproj.tif', 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
      rio.warp.reproject(
            source=rio.band(src, 1),
            destination=rio.band(dst, 1),
            src_transform=src.transform,
            src_crs=src.crs,
            dst_transform=transform,
            dst_crs=dst_crs,
            resampling=rio.warp.Resampling.bilinear)
```

Problem:

After reprojecting 1st time with it's own projection which is not defined I have seen change in pixel size from 1000 meter to 999.9999 meter. Which eventually giving results of less  rows and columns.
In ArcMap defining projection and reprojection steps are different. However, I could not find how to define the projection by using Python. So that I have re projected it twice.

I want to have the same AOI with same rows and columns from both of the data so that I could burn the product without getting an error message.
If anyone could help me to find solution of my problem I am literally stuck with the reprojection.